# Starting Android Learning

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently i've started android training, and i've got the below 2 issues.

1. In my desktop i already had eclipse installed, and when trying to import the android plugins, I was getting some error, so what i did was downloaded eclipse+android package from android developers website and I copied it onto my programs files folder where java is installed and when i open it, it is throwing me an error saying the javaw is not found, goinf through the earlier posts on SO website, i've tried the below.

   -vm
   \adding the java path

But this didn't work for me. so what i did was installed the same package in my laptop(there is no another eclipse on my laptop). and it started working fine.

2. On my laptop in the eclipse+android package i write a program and when i hit the `Android virtual device manager`, it asks me to create a AVD, and when i've filled the entire data here, the `OK` button is still greyed out. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Also i've tried to create by creating from Device definition,even here i'm not getting the ok button hoghlighted and below is its screenshot

[image]
please let me know how can i fix the above issues.

Thanks

Comment: select your skin and decrease memory to 512 http://www.7solutions.in/2014/04/windowslinuxmac-how-to-install-android.html

Comment: Run eclipse and everything as administrator, this catches me out a lot. Add your skin and try varying the memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need not wonder for such a mess ..

For IDE purpose .. go to this link .. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Android Studio IDE contains all you need .. Just download ..extract and start creating your first Android project.

And now for tutorials to learn .. try these site ..

(1) https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=6 ( Travis ... provide best tutorial in this world )

(2) https://developer.android.com/index.html

Now you are good to go ..

Answer (score 1):

You can see it clearly says: "CPU/ABI: No system images installed for this target"
So either:

- Lower your target.
- Update your SDK.

Then set a CPU and you can go on in the AVD creation process.

Answer (score 0):

update the sdk, install ARM/intel(x86) for CPU/ABI

Answer (score -2):

Try using Android Studio by IntelliJ ,as it is for more better than eclipse and moreover ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development.
if you then also get the same error again try this link [android Developer](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio) and setup java environment.

Comment: Android Studio is still in beta, and saying its "far more better than eclipse" is entirely subjective.

Comment: @jaytj95 i have ment ioned my opinion thtz all..no offense in that

Comment: sorry,without taking nobody cant state.:)